# Which technology is used for the tags system on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

Which technology is used for the tags system on Stack Overflow? Is it [SignalR](http://signalr.net/)?

Comment: @Stijn actually yes,but I can't find my answer,I know that's C#,but I can't find why don't pages refresh on settings tags?

Comment: What page do you mean? Can you share the url of the page you expect to refresh? They don't use SignalR. They have their own websocket server and client side handling of the socket messages. But not every page has a webscoket connection on it. See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218343/) or search for [websocket](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=websocket)

Comment: @rene Thank you for response,I mean when we set a tag for a question,only that text box refreshes not all the page.

Comment: For that a simple ajax/XmlHttpRequest call is used, no fancy frameworks there.